# Overload resolution not applicable to operator overloading

Tags: c++, overloading

The Standard at `N4296:13.1/1 [over.load]` says:

> A program is ill-formed if it contains two such non-overloadable
>   declarations in the same scope. [ Note: This restriction applies to
>   explicit declarations in a scope, and between such declarations and
>   declarations made through a using-declaration (7.3.3). It does not
>   apply to sets of functions fabricated as a result of name lookup
>   (e.g., because of using-directives) or *overload resolution* (e.g., for
>   operator functions). —end note ]

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    int foo(){ return 1; };
}

using namespace A;

int foo(){ return 1; }

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/573bb399bc207535)**

This will be well-formed untill foo is not odr-used. This is clear and this reperesent the first piece of the note I provided in the quote (about `using-directive`). But I have no idea what the Standard meant about overload resolution for operator functions that I emphasized in the quote. Could you give me an example?

Comment: In your example, the two declarations of `foo` are in different scopes. You can happily odr-use either or both, via `::foo` and `A::foo`. It is true that, if you just call `foo()` from `main` without scope resolution, the program would be ill-formed - but for a different reason: the call is ambiguous, overload resolution fails to find a single best match.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, but what the Standard does is to say that _It does not apply to sets of functions fabricated as a result of name lookup (e.g., because of using-directives) or overload resolution (e.g., for operator functions)._ I just want to look at an example of not applying the rule to the overload resolution, as the note said.

Comment: **13.6/1** The candidate operator functions that represent the built-in operators defined in Clause 5 are specified in
this subclause. These candidate functions participate in the operator overload resolution process as described
in 13.3.1.2 and are used for no other purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace A {
    struct Foo{};
}

namespace B {
    struct Bar{};
}

namespace A {
    int operator+(const A::Foo&, const B::Bar&);
}

namespace B {
    char operator+(const A::Foo&, const B::Bar&);
}

int main() { A::Foo() + B::Bar(); }
```

ADL finds both `A::operator+()` and `B::operator+()`. The two signatures are different only in their return type.